# Sort array by values in a separate hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have a hash mapping array indices to sort values, e.g.

```
{0=>"item_ss", 1=>"item_hsj", 2=>"item_skls"}
```

I have a separate array with `line_item_id` and associated line_items (tab separated) as follows:

```
["item_skls \t sim1\t99\n", "item_ss \t sim2\t54\n", "item_hsj \t sim3\t48\n"]
```

How can I sort the array using the values of the hash as the identifier and the key as the index of for the array?

For example, I want the array above to be sorted as follows:

```
["item_ss \t sim2\t99\n", "item_hsj \t sim3\t54\n", "item_skls \t sim1\t48\n"]
```

Comment: your output array is wrong?

Comment: from where you got `"item_ss \t sim2\t99\n"` ?

Comment: Its from the second element in the array, sorry my output was wrong, fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: @Yogzzz I'm confused. Why do you sort `item_skls` by the value `item_ss` and so on?

Comment: @Phrogz The index from the hash is associated with item popularity. I am trying to sort the array by the item popularity based on the hash.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["item_skls \t sim1\t99\n", "item_ss \t sim2\t54\n", "item_hsj \t sim3\t48\n"]
h = {0=>"item_ss", 1=>"item_hsj", 2=>"item_skls"}

puts a.sort_by.with_index{ |v,i| h[i] }
#=> item_ss      sim2   54
#=> item_hsj     sim3   48
#=> item_skls    sim1   99
```

Comment: It will work, till the time keys are 0,1,2 instead of any random integer.. :)

Comment: if hash is like `h = {20=>"item_ss", 31=>"item_hsj", 42=>"item_skls"}` .. then ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit As noted in the original question, _"the key as the index of for the array"_.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
hash = {0=>"item_ss", 1=>"item_hsj", 2=>"item_skls"}
array = ["item_skls \t sim1\t99\n", "item_ss \t sim2\t54\n", "item_hsj \t sim3\t48\n"]
array.sort_by { |s| hash.find { |_,v| s.starts_with? v }.first }
# => ["item_ss \t sim2\t54\n",
#     "item_hsj \t sim3\t48\n",
#     "item_skls \t sim1\t99\n"]
```

Comment: use `starts_with?` instead of `include?` to make it faster

Comment: @NewAlexandria Humm.. That depends although.. Anyway changed.